# profilng for Data.HashMap

Tags: haskell, profiling, ghc

I'm using ghc 6.12.2 and the latest Data.HashMap 1.1.0 package, and while compiling with options

```
+RTS -prof -auto-all
```

it does not work, and the message said that I didn't install the profiling package

How to install it ?

Thanks to reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can we assume you're using [this hashmap](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashmap)?  In general, you need to install with profiling: `cabal install -p hashmap --reinstall`.  Most people enable profiling by default (edit your cabal `config` file and set `library-profiling: True`).

Answer (score 1):

You're serious?  GHC 5.2.2 is over 8 years old.

If you get the current [Haskell Platform](http://hackage.haskell.org/platform/), including GHC 6.12.3, we can give relevant advice.

**Edit**: I see you fixed your post.

Comment: And if he actually ment to say 6.12.2 (2 typos) then that's still bad as 6.12.2 has a number of known issues.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the options

```
+RTS -prof -auto-all
```

while building Data.HashMap, or are you just using

```
-prof -auto-all
```

?

The `+RTS` indicates you're giving flags to the haskell run-time system.  You don't use it when you're compiling code, you use it while running a compiled executable.

Comment: while building the executable program of cause

Comment: You don't need `+RTS` when compiling or building, only when running the executable.